# Im getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$s' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having this trouble with php can anyone help me please?
[image: This is my PHP Validation code]

[image: and this is the error i get]

Comment: Im sorry sir I am new to this php i am studying and honestly i cant still find the problem

Comment: You are missing a trailing `;` 3 lines before on the `($con,'test') <<<`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: @mplungjan Out of curiosity, why defining `$s` three lines later fired the error, but defining `$username` on the next line went through ..?

Comment: I fixed the missing ";" but im still getting the same error, Sorry sir im self studying and im just relying on the tutorials that im watching

Comment: Please post the CODE here. Not pictures of code. Then we can look for example here: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: <?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'user');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$s = "select * from usertable where same = '$username' && password = '$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1)
{
 header('location:home.php');
}else
{
 header('location:login.php');
}

?>